# C++ Fibonacci sequence generator using a while loop. What is wrong with my logic here?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

So I tried to create a program using a while loop that asks the user to input a number and that number will be used to essentially generate the fibonacci sequence up to that number. Meaning if the user inputs the number 10 then the output should be the fibonacci numbers up to the maximum number the user inputs like 0,1,1,2,3,5,8.

```
   #include<iostream> 
   
   int main(){

   int F0(0), F1(1), Fnext;
   int num;
   
   std::cout << "Enter a number:\n"; 
   std::cin >> num;
   
   std::cout << F0 << " " << F1;
           while(Fnext <= num){
           Fnext = F1 + F0;
           F0 = F1;
           F1 = Fnext;
           
           }
   std::cout << Fnext;
   }
```

Sorry if my formatting is weird, firs-time user here on this website. I tried to copypaste my code and it didn't work so the code above you is manually typed.

UPDATE:
I updated my code and the output is so close to being right.

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){

int F0(0), F1(1), Fnext(0);
int num;

std::cout << "enter a number to generate the fibonacci sequence up to that number:\n"
std::cin >> num;

std::cout << F0 << " " << F1;

        while(Fnext < num){
         Fnext = F1 + F0;
         F0 = F1;
         F1 = Fnext;
         std::cout << " " << Fnext;
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: put your `std::cout << Fnext;` right after `Fnext = F1 + F0;` inside your while loop and see what you get

Comment: [Seems fine](http://cpp.sh/7p7efz)

Comment: @NathanOliver the ''IDE" I'm using is repl.it and I don't believe it has any debugging tools. I am thinking of switching over to an actual IDE so I can benefit from the debugging features.

Comment: @m88 I see that it runs on your end with the exception that it includes 13...maybe its repl.it's fault? I'll check on another IDE.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz it doesn't even have an output when I do that, the only thing it outputs is 0 and 1.

Comment: Look for two things. When do you first use the `Fnext` variable? When do you first give the `Fnext` variable a value? Your problem is that the first happens before the second.

Comment: Could be a problem with `std::cout`. Try displaying things with either `std::cout << ... << std::flush;` or `std::cout << ... << std::endl;`

Comment: I doubt it will ever enter the while loop, have you considered to initialise the `Fnext`?

Comment: @john THANK YOU! such a silly mistake on my end. It worked out better now! The only issue here now the output is off by one number. You can check what I mean up above I updated my question with the new code!

Comment: @lainos88 THANK YOU TOO! I didn't even realize this...

Comment: Just a suggestion checkout `using namespace std` by this you won't have to rewrite std every time!

Comment: @Matthew The problem is still that you are doing things in the wrong order. You test if `Fnext` is too big and then you calculate it. It should be the other way around. Calculate what the next fibonacci number is, then check if it is too big, if it is then stop, otherwise print it and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

1. You haven't initialized/defined `Fnext`, so it doesn't appear that your code will make it into your while loop, and it won't be displayed.
2. Your `cout` statements are not inside of your loop, so you won't have access to the value (specifically `Fnext`) that you're wanting to display. If you want to display the contents of `Fnext` as it's "incremented" it must be inside of the while loop.

```
#include<iostream> 

int main(){
    int F0(0), F1(1), Fnext(0);
    int num;
    
    std::cout << "Enter a number:\n"; 
    std::cin >> num;
    
    std::cout << F0 << " " << F1;
    while(Fnext <= num){
        Fnext = F1 + F0;
        F0 = F1;
        F1 = Fnext;
        std::cout << Fnext << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized that a bit late and changed my code accordingly. The only issue I have now is that it outputs a number past the user input. You can see what I mean in my updated question above with code very similar to yours!

Comment: That sounds like a good issue to ponder over lunch. At what point is the output of that final number controlled? After that... what symbol would prevent that last number from displaying? Hint: Both answers are somewhere in your while loop.

Comment: inside my while condition I did while(Fnext <= num && (F1 +F0) <= num), I find it to be a nicer solution to the issue vs using an if statement and break; .

Answer (score 0):

First, you should initialise the `Fnext` variable too, and try to add some space or new lines when displaying the output (i.e. `cout`). Secondly, you need to break the `while` loop if the sum of the numbers exceeds the input from the user (if I correctly understood your question).

```
#include<iostream> 

int main(){

  int F0(0), F1(1), Fnext(0);
  int num;
  std::cout << "Enter a number:\n"; 
  std::cin >> num;

  std::cout << "Initial Num: " << F0 << ", " << F1 << ", " << Fnext << ", " << num << std::endl;
  while(Fnext < num){
    if (F1 + F0 >= num)
      break;
    else{
      Fnext = F1 + F0;
      F0 = F1;
      F1 = Fnext;        
    }    
  }
  std::cout << "FINAL: " << Fnext << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see adding the if-else statement inside the loop would help in the case when the sum of the numbers exceeds the number entered by the user! Thank you, I'll try it now.

Answer (score 0):

All answers have been given already. The semantic problem was solved.

For the interested advanced C++ programmers I will show an additional solution

- using compile time precalculated Fibonacci numbers
- and no loop during runtime

I will first show the code and then explain it later:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// All done during compile time -------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    unsigned long long f1{ 0ull }, f2{ 1ull }, f3{};
    while (index--) { f3 = f2 + f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3; }
    return f2;
}
// Some helper to create a constexpr std::array initilized by a generator function
template <typename Generator, size_t ... Indices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(Generator generator, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return std::array<decltype(std::declval<Generator>()(size_t{})), sizeof...(Indices) > { generator(Indices)... };
}
template <size_t Size, typename Generator>
constexpr auto generateArray(Generator generator) {
    return  generateArrayHelper(generator, std::make_index_sequence<Size>());
}
constexpr size_t MaxIndexFor64BitFibonacci = 93;

// This is the definition of a std::array<unsigned long long, 93> with all Fibonacci numbers in it
constexpr auto Fib = generateArray<MaxIndexFor64BitFibonacci>(getFibonacciNumber);
// End of: All done during compile time -----------------------------------------------------------


// The only code executed during runtime
int main() {

    // Give instruction to user:
    std::cout << "\nEnter a number to generate the fibonacci sequence up to that number:\n";

    // Get border value from user
    if (unsigned long long  border{}; std::cin >> border)

        // Show all Fibonacci numbers up to border value
        std::copy(Fib.begin(), std::upper_bound(Fib.begin(), Fib.end(), border), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned long long>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

One important property of the Fibonacci series is that the values grow strongly exponential. So, all existing build in integer data types will overflow rather quick.

With Binet's formula you can calculate that the 93rd Fibonacci number is the last that will fit in a 64bit unsigned value.

A calculation for 93 values can be easily done at compile time.

We will use a generic approach with a "generator" function, and the use this generator function to fill a compile time `constexpr std::array`.

We can basically use all Fibonacci number algorithms for our generator function. So, let's use a default functionality and use the folling constexpr function:

```
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    unsigned long long f1{ 0ull }, f2{ 1ull }, f3{};
    while (index--) { f3 = f2 + f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3; }
    return f2;
}
```

To fill the `constexpr std::array` with the Fibonacci numbers, we use a templated function with a variadic parameter pac. Template arguments are the "generator" function and a `std::index_sequence`, which will give us a 0,1,2,3....

```
// Some helper to create a constexpr std::array initilized by a generator function
template <typename Generator, size_t ... Indices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(Generator generator, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return std::array<decltype(std::declval<Generator>()(size_t{})), sizeof...(Indices) > { generator(Indices)... };
}
```

This will call our `generator` function with all indices and store the result in the `std::array` at that index position.

The type of the data in the `std::array` will be deduced from the return type of the generator function. So this is a rather flexible approach.

With an additional templated `constexpr` function, we define the maximum index as argument. In our case it will be 93.

```
template <size_t Size, typename Generator>
constexpr auto generateArray(Generator generator) {
    return  generateArrayHelper(generator, std::make_index_sequence<Size>());
}
```

And now, finally, we will create our `constexpr std::array<unsigned long long, 93>` containing all Fibonacci numbers fitting in a 64 bit value.

```
constexpr auto Fib = generateArray<MaxIndexFor64BitFibonacci>(getFibonacciNumber);
```

With that we can easily get the ith Fibonacci number by a simple lookup mechanism. And, we can use algorithms from the C++ standard library to operate on those numbers.

This we can see in the function `main` where we use `std::copy` and `std::upperbound` to copy the requested Fibonacci numbers to `std::cout`, without using any loop.

This approach usually gives very compact and very fast solutions.

The above described generator mechanism is very flexible and can also be used to calculate other sequences. Simply exchange the generator function.

All the above is valid for C++17

Developed and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2

Additionally tested with gcc 10.2 and clang 11.0.1 and flags "-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic"